# what is the access specifier of the top level class in the intermediate language code?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Default access specifier of top level classes in c# is internal 
but when I observed the IL code it was as follows

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit n.A
   extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
} // end of class n.A
```

instead of assembly keyword why is the compiler using private keyword in the above IL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IL defines things differently than C#; in IL there is *visibility* and *accessibility*. The details of this are in II.10.1 and table II.10.1.1 of ECMA 335. The only two valid options for top-level types are `public` and `private` - everything else relates to `nested *`, i.e. types within types.

So essentially, it does this *because the specification demands it*:

> A type that is not nested inside another type shall have exactly one visibility (**private** or **public**) and shall not have an accessiblity.

There is no such thing as `assembly` or `family` for top level types.